# How to install LibreOffice Manually in Lubuntu 13.04?

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice

How to install LibreOffice Manually in Lubuntu 13.04 ?
i have downloaded a **LibreOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz** and when i extract i found 2 folders and 1 file, when i click install and new box appear there i click execute but nothing happen.

Please guide me how to install LibreOffice using .gz downloaded file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the `readmes` subdirectory (it's the second folder created after you extracted the `.tar.gz`). It contains a readme file with a description how to install the application.

It's just one command to issue from inside a console window. To open a console window, open a file manager and select the parent folder of `readmes` and `DEBS` (it' named `LibreOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_deb`). Do a right-click on the `DEBS` directory and select `Open in Terminal`. Now, enter the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

You may have to enter your password, afterwards the installation should run without any other interaction.